# How to survive in an Antimatter Universe/Dimension?

Tags: alternate-reality, space-travel

So, in my Science Fiction story, my character, Bryan, has just gotten (seemingly) the worst punishment anybody could ever get. A group of terrorists have just blown him out of an airlock, near the biggest Black Hole in the Galaxy. He's extremely scared and thinks that once he enters the Black Hole, he's dead. But, something incredibly strange happens.

He goes into the Black Hole, gets stretched nearly to death, and then, he comes back out. He turns around and sees a White Hole, burping out material into the....he realizes the place he is in is strange. Black dots and a white void are impossible in Bryan's Uni....he then realizes that he’s in a Universe that’s somehow a negative of the place he just left, like a blueprint Bryan once learned about in school. This Universe he’s in as made out of Antimatter, and he instantly urinates on himself.

Bryan is well versed in science and knows that when matter and antimatter come together, it causes an earth-shattering kaboom. And that is with just a few grams of Antimatter, but Bryan is a 180 lbs. grown human, if he contacts anything, without some sort of protection, it's gonna kill him. He turns on his jetpack and sees a group of junk ships and vessels. He tries to get away because he thinks their Antimatter, but he realizes it's just clutter from his old home.

He finds a man, Dr. Heinrich Von Braun, who went missing 20 years ago around the area of the Black Hole. He’s the only one, even though his ship had 13 other people on it. He tells Bryan that the other crew members went insane, got into the escape pods and tried to find a planet to inhabit. The found one and....well, you know...KABOOM. Dr. Von Braun wants to try and find a way back home, and he thinks by finding a Black Hole in this Universe, he could travel through it and get back to the normal universe. But there is a problem. The two men are made out of Matter, along with their ship, but to get to a Black Hole, they would need to travel through the Universe, which can be filled with particles rocks and other debris that would utterly destroy them if they contacted each other.

So my question is: How could two beings, made out of 100% pure Matter, protect themselves from an Antimatter universe.

- It's okay for your answers to be out there, as long as it's grounded in real science

Comment: No time for an answer right now, but: Honkin' great magnetic fields, good timing and prayer.

Comment: *"Black dots and a white void"* is something you will not get simply by switching to antimatter.

Comment: [Reminder to close-voters](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3773/6986): The problem cannot be fixed if the OP is not made aware of it.

Comment: some theories of antimatter do predict that it "falls" away from normal matter, this would mean that the answer to your question is absolutely nothing. that however does not, a good story make

Comment: @Molot: It’s supposed to be like a Negative of the original universe

Comment: @Aify: I’m a new user. What’s making you so suspicious, I only logged on the sites few days ago

Comment: @Aify: What’s making you so suspicious

Comment: The White Hole, unless it's located outside of a galaxy, will be making a lot of bang with all the "normal matter junk" that is falling though. Dust and particles from our universe will be meeting dust and particles from another universe. Eventually, every bit of "normal matter" will collide and annihilate. This will shine like a quasar.

Comment: It's not your question, but related:  we observe "white" as a result of photons hitting the eye, and "black" as a result of photons not hitting the eye.  It would be very difficult to explain why this would occur without magic, or the main character hitting his head and suddenly seeing everything funny.

Comment: True, we really don't know about conditions inside a black hole, or if it leads at all in another universe via a manifestation called white hole. That is speculation, and any author can stretch disbelief with that.
The real problem here is: The EXACT moment the ship crosses the Event Horizon, it finds itself facing the most monstrous gravitational well in nature. It just doesn't get stretched: It is is RIPPED APART at the speed of light, while the other half opposite to the black hole is still not feeling the G pull.
The ship is destroyed, instantly, totally. Sayonara

Comment: I suggest you remove the word antimatter and just replace it with anti-universe, antimatter has known properties whereas your anti-universe can have whatever properties you define. You can't ask for something grounded in real science is a universe that does not obey most known scientific laws.

Comment: @Valerio Pastore - not at a supermassive black hole. With Event Horizon sufficiently away from central singularity, crossing horizon should not cause any dramatic gravitational effects.

Comment: @Alexander - The moment our hero's body is getting spaghettified, there is no turning back -'stretching' is a severe underestimation. The tidal forces will play havoc with his body to a cellular level. If even worse, he'd have the dubious privilege of suffering a bit longer, in this case.
Plus, there is the expulsion: A white hole wouldn't likely reconstruct the objects and burp them out brand as new. Our hero would be anyway cooked by the WH's radiation. if he wasn't dead before, he'd be dead now

Comment: @Valerio Pastore if we allow "wormholes" to exist, crossing event horizon becomes "turn back point". As [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification) suggests, spaghettification may occur much close to a singularity, which means the hypothetical traveler will be safe from it.

Comment: @Alexander - Ok. I'm game for the wormhole.
They're dead anyay. A white hole is, according to the most acceptable models, a gamma-ray burst source. The moment  it expels something, anything, it also fries it. No spacesuit can save our hero from that.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRB_060614

Answer (score 4):

You don't.

For stuff that is not electrically charged - and that's most things in the universe - you don't know if something is matter or antimatter until you touch it. For stuff that is charged, you'd need to first measure the charge. No matter how creative you get here, at some point it becomes unfeasible. So your characters will have to avoid touching everything.

A personal shield that keeps anything and everything away is the stuff of [magic](/questions/tagged/magic). So either you accept that the only possible answer is contained and sumarized in the word *magic*, or you accept that sooner than later the protagonist will die. At least he will go out with a bang.

Seriously. According to [a *XKCD What If* that is tangentially relevant:](https://what-if.xkcd.com/114/)

> Outer space isn't really "space"; it's full of a thin gas.

The best your characters can do to survive the longest possible is to stay put. Even then they are on borrowed time, because whatever ship they are in will disintegrate after finite time.

Comment: I’m not going for total realism, Renan. And their is no Magic in my world, so just use your  IMAGINATION and try and help me. I can’t think of anything myself

Comment: No total realism and no magic are mutually exclusive. Call it Green Lantern physics if you will, it's still magic. Don't be ashamed to just state things as ypu did in the question, and throw buzzwords around - that is exactly what geniuses like Stan Lee did and still do. Or do you think people dislike the Hulk because "that's not how gamma radiation works"?

Comment: But green lanterns stuff is powered by solid light, I think, not magic?

Comment: @JasperR. I fail to see the difference.

Comment: Oh I see what you’re talking about. Is it at least possible or have black stars and a white void?

Comment: @JasperR. Dying stars are pitch black... And ultimately, the only limit to what is possible is your imagination.

Comment: @JasperR. you can't get black spots in a white void, if space itself is emitting ligth you won't be able to see the dark patches, because the space between you and the black star will be emitting light.

Comment: @Joun: No it is not emitting light

Comment: You may want to read the Larry Niven story Flatlander which is about a normal ship trying to orbit aan antimatter star, the ship that withstand falling into a normal star disintegrates in a few hours just from the antimatter solar wind.

Comment: @JasperR. Then what is emitting light, a star emitting light will not be black and you cant see white without light.

Comment: @John: In this universe stars emitt cold, and animals in this universe survive off cold, and live in Darkness, and etc.

Comment: @then its magic, things can't emit cold, this also means the void is not white it is pitchblack like everything else. a universe without light can't have mateer, anti- or otherwise.

Comment: @John: You didn’t get the reference? It’s a joke

Comment: It's not really funny, Jasper. People are trying to help you out and you're being deliberately vague and wasting their time. Bottom line is this: You've devised a scenario so far beyond and outside of the laws of Physics that it can't exist, so do whatever you want and please don't complain when other people don't do that work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need the strongest magnetic fields you can get to direct charged particles away, and you need strong lasers and amazingly sensitive radar to aim them to push neutral particles away.  Even individual anti-neutrons must be avoided because they will ablate the hull of your ship if they hit it.  And since you're in an anti-matter universe, there's no regular matter around for you to make repairs.  All damage is permanent.

Comment: individual anti-neutrons would not actually be found in free space since they would quickly decay to anti-protons and anti-electrons

Comment: *"you need strong lasers and amazingly sensitive radar to aim them to push neutral particles away."* And a good lawyer too, because you will need to break some of the laws of physics to have an energy source that will allow you to do that. You'd need more than the annual output of the sun just to deflect a small asteroid.

Comment: All damage isn’t necessarily permanent. Their are hundreds of ships that have been caught in the Black Hole that they can use for repairs

Comment: @Renan No not necessarily. photons carry enough momentum for it to even be considered viable in the near future for space trash clearing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_broom and if you are in the ISM (as i think the question implies) theres not much that needs to be pushed away

Comment: Static electric fields would be enough to divert charged particles but you'd need to vary the charge distribution to deflect either positive or negative ions (you'd need to do this anyway with a magnetic field, but with the added complication of closed field-line loops). [Diamagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism) might keep some rocks away if they have enough graphite in them. Might.